# passing ajax div result in a variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have retrieve email address result from a database using ajax and then output it in a div and everything works fine using the code below

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".link_chat").click(function() {
        var email_id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(email_id);


 var dataString = 'email_id='+ email_id;
  if(confirm("Are you Sure you want to get email address."))
          {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "email.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {


                    $("#email").html(data);

                } 
            });
          }
        });
 });

</script>

<div id="email"></div>
```

email.php

```
<?php
echo $email="example@gmail.com";
?>
```

Now my question is how can I pass the ajax result(email)  to `User_Email` variable as in the case below instead of passing it in div. for example

```
<div>
      <main
      user_email="example@gmail.com"
      />
    </div>
```

I have also tried code below but cannot get it to work

```
<div>
          <main
          user_email="email" id="email"
          />
        </div>
```

Comment: Any reason your response has this kind of html data? Your email.php could also simply return the email address if any was found. I am guessing the selector you are looking for is either `$('div main')[0].getAttribute('user_email')` or `$('main [user_email]')[0].getAttribute('user_email')`

Comment: Am not looking for any selector. The Code above is working fine. it outputs the email address eg example@gmail.com in div hence i used this <div id="email"></div>. my question is how do I pass this outputted  email address to variable user_email instead of passing it in a div

Comment: So you're trying to pass data fetched in the AJAX request to a tag attribute? I'd suggest revising the question to clarify what it is you wish to accomplish.